# Eclipse not importing project to workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to import project from existing code in android . but it is not importing complete project . There is java code in src folder and some images in assets folder but it is not importing to my workspace,other folder are importing to the workspace.

Comment: i am using that option

Comment: but it left some files over there so it is creating some probelm

Comment: Is this an eclipse project ?

Comment: Yes android project but has it been developed in eclipse or not ?

Comment: dont know i have get this code from my client

Comment: make one `res` folder and then again try to import it.

Comment: res folder in project ?

Comment: yes, just like normal android project has res folder

Comment: but it is allerady exist in my project it is importing the project but not the file inside it

Comment: how many folders you have in your project folder ?

Comment: all android project folder but probem is this when i am importing the project then it is not importing the files inside that project it importing only the folders in workspace

Comment: @user3568668 Show the folder structure of your project by capturing screenshot and post it in your question. Also make sure your project contains `Project.property` file. Because sometimes it happens that if this file is missing then also it doesn't import project.